# SecurityError from Facebook and Cross Domain Messaging

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, cross-domain, facebook-javascript-sdk

We have an application that utilizes the facebook javascript sdk and login capabilities.

We've been noticing this error come up in our production logs. Specifically for iOS devices with versions 10.3 and higher. Also seems to only be targeting safari browsers

> SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://www.mymadeupsite.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "https://staticxx.facebook.com". The frame being accessed set
>   "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame requesting access
>   did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow
>   access.

Here is our init function:

```
        init: function(options) {
            var facebookUrl, scriptInclude;
            Facebook.baseHost = options.baseHost;
            if (typeof FB !== "undefined" && FB !== null) {
                return Facebook.setup();
            } else {
                if (options.appId == null) {
                    throw 'Facebook: cannot init without appId';
                }
                window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.init({
                        appId: options.appId,
                        version    : 'v2.3',
                        channelUrl: options.channelUrl || ("" + document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.host + "/channel.html"),
                        status: true,
                        cookie: false,
                        xfbml: false,
                        oauth: true
                    });
                    return Facebook.setup();
                };
                $('body').append('<div id="fb-root"></div>');
                facebookUrl = "//connect.facebook.net/" + (Facebook.getLocaleFacebookSupports(Social.SETTINGS.fbLocale)) + "/sdk.js";
                scriptInclude = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" async=\"true\" src=\"" + facebookUrl + "\"></script>";
                return $('#fb-root').append(scriptInclude);
            }
        }
```

My question, why are we only getting this error on iOS devices and versions 10.3?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well, and after digging around it seems to be a bug in the browser's autofill: the stacktrace that is send to our logging cluster looks as followed:

```
g@https://example.com:5:190, 
g@https://example.com:7:323, 
extractNewForms@https://example.com:13:37, 
extractForms@https://example.com:8:381, 
global code@https://example.com:1:98
```

As you can see, the error happens somewhere in an `extractForms` function, which (for us) doesn't exist anywhere in the code base. A Google search reveals that both `extractForms` and `extractNewForms` are part of the browser's autofill library, and the thread [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=590375) suggests that there is a bug in there (comments 12 & 15 are most relevant to your issue).

As far as I can tell this is also not specifically related to Facebook: in our logs we see similar errors for more iframes, including iframes from (sub)domains we control ourselves.

Unfortunately I don't know about any fix or workaround, and I also highly doubt if a (user-land) fix/workaround is actually possible. I think the only thing you can do is to ignore these errors.

Comment: Should be fixed as of Chrome 59 (May 2017) according to the thread you linked to.

Comment: I have same bug on my website. Only users from ipad and iphone experience it.

Comment: Just had a bunch of error reports for this as well, came from iOS 10.3.1 and Chrome 60