# iframe security error - only on Chrome for iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, security, iframe

I'm seeing a security error on my site.

`SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.my-site.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.google.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

This is strange for two reasons -

**1** - 100% of occurrences are in Chrome for iOS.

**2** - all of the similar errors on Stack Overflow I see of this type are the reverse situation; the iframe attempting to access the enclosing page.

Any insight into what's going on here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46050071

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be duplicated by

[SecurityError from Facebook and Cross Domain Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399818/securityerror-from-facebook-and-cross-domain-messaging)

as well as

[Facebook iFrame security error (document.domain) raised by hasPasswordField_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050071/facebook-iframe-security-error-document-domain-raised-by-haspasswordfield)